# Unable to install modules for anaconda

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

```
abhigenie92@ubuntu:~/Desktop/pygame-1.9.1release$ which python
/home/abhigenie92/anaconda/bin/python
abhigenie92@ubuntu:~/Desktop/pygame-1.9.1release$ sudo apt-get install python-pygame
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-pygame is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 224 not upgraded.
abhigenie92@ubuntu:~/Desktop/pygame-1.9.1release$ python 
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:02:03) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

What is happening above? It seems to not install for anaconda. But it is directing to the right from path.

Comment: Have you tried installing from anacondas installation of pip?

Comment: @Simon I tried `sudo pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`
It shows `Successfully installed pygame`. But still anaconda python shows no such module.

Comment: I'm not sure if anaconda sets up any kind of virtualenv - I would assume that it does. I don't use anaconda on linux, but on windows to install using anacondas pip I would do: `/home/abhigenie92/anaconda/bin/pip.exe install pygame`. Linux comes with its own python install, and instaling anaconda will install a second, so you'd need to navigate to where anacondas pip is and install modules using that. Using `sudo pip install pygame` will just use the base python that came with linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are installing things into the system Python. You need to install into the Anaconda Python, using `pip install pygame` (note that `sudo pip` is likely going to use the system Python again, and using `sudo` with the Anaconda Python is not recommended anyway).